# whats the difference between @Provide and @Inject in dagger2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

Whats the difference between @Inject and @Provide ?

although both are used for providing dependencies then whats the difference ?

Answer (score 5):

This is covered very well in [documentation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/), `@Inject` and `@Provides` are two different ways of introducing dependencies in the dependency graph. they are suited for different use cases

### `@Inject`

1. Easy to use, simply add `@Inject` on constructor or property and you are done
2. It can be used to inject types as well as type properties
3. In a subjective way it may seem clearer than `@Provides` to some people

### `@Provides`

1. If you don't have access to source code of the type that you want to inject then you can't mark its constructor with `@Inject`
2. In some situations you may want to configure an object before you introduce it in dependency graph, this is not an option with `@Inject`
3. Sometimes you want to introduce an Interface as a dependency, for this you can create a method annotated with `@Provides` which returns Inteface type

---

**Following are the examples of above three points for `@Provides`**

---

### If you can't access source code of a type

```
// You can't mark constructor of String with @Inject but you can use @Provides

@Provides
fun provideString(): String {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

### Configure an object before introducing in the dependency graph

```
@Provides
fun provideCar(): Car {
    val car = Car()
    // Do some configuration before introducing it in graph, you can't do this with @Inject
    car.setMaxSpeed(100)
    car.fillFuel()
    return car
}
```

### Inject interface types in dependency graph

```
interface Logger { fun log() }
class DiscLogger : Logger{ override fun log() { } }
class MemoryLogger : Logger { override fun log() { } }

@Provides
fun provideLogger(): Logger {
    val logger = DiscLogger() \\ or MemoryLogger()
    return logger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Inject:- It is used to inject dependencies in class.
@provides:- Required to annotated the method with @provide where actual instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

This has covered in [Dagger-2](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/) documentation clearly.

**What @Inject can Do:**

- Use @Inject to annotate the constructor that Dagger should use to
  create instances of a class. When a new instance is requested, Dagger
  will obtain the required parameters values and invoke this
  constructor.
- If your class has @Inject-annotated fields but no @Inject-annotated
  constructor, Dagger will inject those fields if requested, but will
  not create new instances. Add a no-argument constructor with the
  @Inject annotation to indicate that Dagger may create instances as
  well.
- Similarly dagger can create for methods also.
- Classes that lack @Inject annotations cannot be constructed by
  Dagger.

**What @Inject can't Do:** and can be used @Provides annotation

- Interfaces can’t be constructed.
- Third-party classes can’t be annotated.
- Configurable objects must be configured!